# datatables selected row background color

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm a newbie so bear with me; I'm using jQuery datatables plugin and I need to select a row and change the color of the selcted row. I followed this [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) from datatables but it doesn't work for me.

This is how i initialize the table:

```
var oTable = $("#rolesTable").dataTable({
    // "bJQueryUI": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        {"sType": "role"},
        null,
        null
    ],
    "aaSorting": [[1, "desc"], [0, "asc"]]
});
```

and this is the code for the click event and the CSS class:

```
<style>
.row_selected tr {
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
```

```
$("#rolesTable tbody tr").click(function (event) {
    $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function () {
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
    });
    $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
});
```

Sorry, I added the click handler

Comment: have you added `$("#example tbody").click(function(event) {
  $(oTable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
   $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
  });
  $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
 }); ` ?

Comment: U need to follow this link: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_single_row.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because class `row_selected` is added to `<tr>` element, so your selector doesn't match anything.

Moreover, `background-color` is added to `<td>` elements (your custom color is 'under' default selected color).

Try :

```
.row_selected td {
    background-color: black !important; /* Add !important to make sure override datables base styles */
 }
```

Comment: this does work, but id doesn't change the background for ALL the td elements; the first column (who's bacground is set by datatables css) does'nt change background

Comment: @Octavian Epure : You can try to add `!important` to force override datables base styles

Answer (score 5):

In the latest Datatables version 1.10.12 you have to do something like this:

```
 .even.selected td {
           background-color: rgb(0,170,0); !important; /* Add !important to make sure override datables base styles */
  }

 .odd.selected td {
          background-color: rgb(0,0,230); !important; /* Add !important to make sure override datables base styles */
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:
You'll have to change grid id name:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grid tr').click(function () {

            $(this).css('background-color', "#D6D5C3");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.table tr.row_selected td {
background-color: #### !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for those who use datatables and Bootstrap 3 in the same project:
I use Visual Studio and I have a MVC project which also includes Bootstrap 3. If I removed Bootstrap from my project, I noticed both odd and even rows are highlighted when selected, so I assumed there must be something in Bootstrap that overwrites the background color of selected rows.

The next Boostrap code already exists in bootstrap.css and what it does is change the background color for the odd lines.

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

I tested adding the following code to the bootstrap.css, just AFTER the previous code lines. I don't find this solution elegant, but it worked for me.

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr.selected > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr.selected > th {
  background-color: #A9D0F5; /* change #A9D0F5 by the color of your preference */ 
}
```